# OpenSSl certificates management

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate, mamp

I'm trying to complete a entire process of request/verify of a trusted timestamp. I'm working with a TSA server and i'm able to create a valid timestamp request. I know that it's valid because tsa owner has a webpage dedicated to the timestamping request validation.
Anyway i have to do this process programmatically, so i'm using openssl to verify:

```
openssl ts -verify -queryfile request.tsq -in result.tsr -CAfile tsaownercert.pem
```

this command produce always:

```
TS_VERIFY_CERT:certificate verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I'm working local with Mamp but also online in a CentOs server the behaviour is the same.

- Files involved in command are reachables.
- `tsaownercert.pem` is a certificate i get from the tsa owner, they sayd
  "it is the certificate in wich the timestamp are signed"

Maybe i have to do some kind of installation of the certificate in the system to make it available ? How i can do it in Mamp and i how in the server ?

Answer (score 1):

From OpenSSL's man page:

> **-CAfile trusted_certs.pem**
>
> The name of the file containing a set of trusted self-signed CA certificates in PEM format. See the similar
>   option of verify(1) for additional details. Either this option or
>   -CApath must be specified. (Optional)
>
> **-untrusted cert_file.pem**
>
> Set of additional untrusted certificates in PEM format which may be needed when building the certificate chain for
>   the TSA's signing certificate. This file must contain the TSA signing
>   certificate and all intermediate CA certificates unless the response
>   includes them. (Optional)

Therefore `-CAfile` should point to the self-signed Root CA while all subordinate CAs including the TS signing certificate should be in he file pointed to by `-untrusted` if they are not in the original response (`result.tsr`).